# Strange browser parsing behavior with background-image: url() and single quotes in URL

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've encountered an odd instance of URL parsing in Google Chrome (doesn't happen in latest IE, don't have FF installed to test).

Inline CSS:

```
background-image: url(http://dev.manager/for/wines/show_2010-meritage-hawk\'s-flight-reserve-750mL.jpg);
```

produces:

```
background-image: url('http://dev.manager/wines/2010-meritage-hawk\'s-flight-reserve-750mL/\'http://dev.manager/for/wines/show_2010-meritage-hawk\'s-flight-reserve-750mL.jpg\'')
```

Has anyone else encountered this before?

Comment: Both single quote and double quote are string delimiters. Try wrap the string inside `url()` in double quotes: `url("http://dev.manager/for/wines/show_2010-meritage-hawk\'s-flight-reserve-750mL.jpg")`. You should not omit quotes around the string if the string itself contains a quote.

Comment: I would try replacing that escaped apostrophe with `%27`.

Comment: Is there even a problem? Or do you just wanted to tell us that you found out that strange behavior of Chrome?

Comment: Are you looking at the raw source, or at the debugger?

Comment: The "Inline CSS" is the raw source and the "produces" is what's found in Inspector.

Comment: And using double quotes wrapping the URL is bad form when using inline CSS considering that the style attribute uses double quotes. It would be like writing: style="background-image:url("some-url");"